# Update a Linq to XML Element with an Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an Add and an Update function to update a listing in an xml database I'm working on.  In the add function i do this:

```
new XElement(ImageUtilities.GetImageXElement(series.image)),
```

It basically takes an image object, does some background stuff (which works fine) and returns an XElement. This works flawlessly.  The problem comes when I am trying to do an update. I'm essentially trying to do the following.

```
xseries.SetElementValue(ImageUtilities.GetImageXElement(series.image));
```

I've tried the following which obviously doesn't work, but I am thinking that some variation of it will work, it compiles, but it wont run.  It gives the error: "System.ArgumentException: An XObject cannot be used as a value." I've googled it, and nothing seems to say, You update an element with an element by.

```
xseries.SetElementValue("image", ImageUtilities.GetImageXElement(series.image));
```

I am able to get it to work properly by doing:

```
xseries.Element("image").SetAttributeValue("guid", series.image.guid);
xseries.Element("image").SetAttributeValue("main", series.image.main);
xseries.Element("image").SetAttributeValue("height", series.image.height);
xseries.Element("image").SetAttributeValue("width", series.image.width);
xseries.Element("image").SetAttributeValue("order", series.image.order);
... and so on.
```

but if the image object changes I'll have to go back in and change everything I've done later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing existing `<image>` element with new `<image>`? You can use [`ReplaceWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do so :

```
xseries.Element("image")
       .ReplaceWith(ImageUtilities.GetImageXElement(series.image));
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! It was driving me batty.  I knew there had to be a good way.

Comment: Good to know your problem solved this simple way. Don't forget to accept an answer at last (it's okay if you're still waiting for other possible solution)